# What's the basic principle of this "tap" function of Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch

As the picture shows, can anyone explain the basic principle of this "tap" function of Apple Watch? 
If not using cellphone, how to realize this function by other means?
the picture is seen by
http://www.apple.com/cn/watch/new-ways-to-connect/

Comment: It is the difference between tap & touch

Comment: Yes, it is. But what I'd like to know is the baisc information cycling. Mainly about the principle of communication. Do you know that?